# Delphi. Show parent window from child

Tags: windows, forms, delphi

I have a small app with two windows. When I open second form - first form hides:

```
procedure TIndexForm.startButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  workingForm.Show(); // show second form
  IndexForm.Hide(); // hide first form

end;
```

But if second window is closed - app still runnig(that's right). But, I want to open first window when second is closed:

```
procedure TworkingForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject);
begin
  parent.Show();
end;
```

And this code dont't work... How I can do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Some advice. Don't say "this code doesn't work". Tell us what you expect to happen, and what actually happens. If there are error messages, include them verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've used the wrong event. You appear to be showing and hiding the form. So you want to attach the event to `OnHide` rather than `OnClose`.

It's also a mistake to call `Show` on `Parent`. The `Parent` of a windows control is it's containing control. For example when you put a button inside a panel, the button's parent is the panel. In you situation you want to call `Show` on the other form.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems. First, that's not a real `OnClose` event handler. In Visual Basic, you could create event handlers simply by typing their names in your code, but in Delphi, their names are irrelevant. They need to be hooked up to the event property of the form or control, and I can tell this one isn't hooked up because the `OnClose` event expects two parameters, not one. Double-click the event in the Object Inspector to have the IDE generate an event handler with the right parameters for you and automatically hook it to the event.

Second, the form you want to show is not `Parent`. That's obvious because if a parent window is hidden, then so are all its children. Your two forms therefore don't have a parent-child relationship.

If you want to show the other form, just use the same technique you used to hide it in the first place:

```
IndexForm.Show;
```

Comment: For use `IndexForm.Show` method I need to add first form unit(because it's not avaliable from second unit), but this - out of memory error..

Comment: Nothing in this question has anything to do with running out of memory. That's an entirely separate problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this example Parent is not assigned to the first form.
You need add unit with first form in the implementation uses clause or
call something like
Application.MainForm.Show;